# flag redefined: Can two components have same flag variable

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-flag

I have a  deployment with 5 containers.
Among them two of them have `--endpoint` as argument for which value is set from `ENV`

So I see this error after deployment

```
/home/xxx-csi-drivers/xxx-vpc-block-csi-driver flag redefined: endpoint
panic: /home/xxx-csi-drivers/xxx-vpc-block-csi-driver flag redefined: endpoint
```

The code from which container A is build has

```
endpoint = flag.String("endpoint", "/tmp/storage-secret-sidecar.sock", "Storage secret sidecar endpoint")
```

also
The code from which container B is build also has

```
endpoint       = flag.String("endpoint", "unix:/tmp/csi.sock", "CSI endpoint")
```

Is defining the same var `endpoint` in the code reason for the above bug.

I have tried changing `arg` names in `deployment` file. and other options which didnt help. But changing `flag` name in code fixed the issue but need to undersatnd more on working. So posted this question

Comment: Thanks @Penelope Stevens
Trying to understand little bit more. Arent the packages independent of each other and they are running in different containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the different containers. Whichever process is crashing is just broken, the code has a bug where it registers the same flag twice which isn't allowed.